# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException when parsing simple JSON Inputstream

Tags: aem

I am getting com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException when parsing simple JSON Inputstream

My json is this.

{
    "logdata": [{
            "millis": "1000",
            "light": "333"
        },
        {
            "millis": "2000",
            "light": "333"
        }
    ]
}

Java class -

```
import java.util.List;
public class Datalist {

private List<NavData> logdata;

/**
 * @return the logdata
 */
public List<NavData> getLogdata() {
    return logdata;
}

/**
 * @param logdata the logdata to set
 */
public void setLogdata(List<NavData> logdata) {
    this.logdata = logdata;
}
```

public class NavData {

```
private String millis;

private String light;

/**
 * @return the millis
 */
public String getMillis() {
    return millis;
}

/**
 * @param millis the millis to set
 */
public void setMillis(String millis) {
    this.millis = millis;
}

/**
 * @return the light
 */
public String getLight() {
    return light;
}

/**
 * @param light the light to set
 */
public void setLight(String light) {
    this.light = light;
}
```

}

Json Input Stream Reader Class - Whereas assetData is the inputStream of above json.

```
   JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(assetData, "UTF-8"));
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

   Datalist out = gson.fromJson(reader, Datalist.class);

   System.out.println(".."+out.getLogdata());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you can't cast a list of string to a list with these items:

```
{
 "millis": "1000",
 "light": "333",
 "temp": "78.32",
 "vcc": "3.54"
}
```

If you want to cast to a list of these items, you need to create a class with these items and the property will be:

```
@Expose
private List<NavData> logdata;
```

Where **NavData** is a class with these parameters

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
public class NavData {
  @Expose
  private String millis;
  @Expose
  private String light;

  public String getMillis() {
      return millis;
  }
  public void setMillis(String millis) {
      this.millis = millis;
  }
  public String getLight() {
      return light;
  }
  public void setLight(String light) {
      this.light = light;
  }
}
```

To read the inputStream :

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.allocate(1024);

while (yourInputStream.read(charBuffer) > 0) {
      charBuffer.flip();
      stringBuilder.append(charBuffer.toString());
      charBuffer.clear();
}
```

finally :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
    .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().serializeNulls().create();

Datalist result = gson.fromJson(stringBuilder.toString(), Datalist.class);
```

Comment: I have updated the details in this ticket to match what you said. But still i see the same JsonSyntaxException. Can you please provide some more inputs please?

Comment: also, i am getting this - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was END_DOCUMENT at line 6 column 1 path $

Comment: Hi SergioEscudero - In my scenario, input is "inputStream but not String". And as i see in below method, "StringToCast" iS String. So Should i convert inputStream into String?                                      Datalist result = gson.fromJson("StringToCast", Datalist.class);